# How to pause blinking christmas lights with a christmas song in CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm working on a CSS animation where I have blinking lights on a Christmas tree on beat to a Christmas song, and when I press on the button below the tree to pause the songs the lights will also pause blinking. And when I press the button again to play the song the light will resume blinking.

This is what I have so far. I've managed to get the lights to blink but when I tried adding audio it doesn't run.

```js
let play = false;

const lights = document.querySelectorAll('.light');
const christmasSong = document.getElementById('christmasSong');
const audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(christmasSong);
audioSource.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

function pauseButton() {
  if (play === false) {
    lights.forEach(light => {
      light.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    });
    christmasSong.play();
    gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, audioContext.currentTime);
    play = true;
  } else {
    lights.forEach(light => {
      light.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    });
    christmasSong.pause();
    gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, audioContext.currentTime);
    play = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.christmas-tree {
  top: 10%;
}

.play-pause {
  /* top: 50%; */
  padding-top: 30px;
  left: 23%;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #d21d1d;
}

.tree-top {
  top: 2%;
  left: 14%;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 160px solid green;
  /* animation: move 2s infinite; */
}

.tree-middle {
  margin-top: -15%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 160px solid green;
  /* animation: move 2s infinite; */
}

.tree-bottom {
  margin-top: -20%;
  margin-left: 7%;
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 160px solid green;
  /* animation: move 2s infinite; */
}

.lights-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.lights-middle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -115px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.lights-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -120px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
}


/* BLINKING LIGHTS */

.light {
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: blink 1s infinite alternate;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.light-red {
  background-color: #f00;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.light-yellow {
  background-color: rgb(246, 255, 0);
  animation-duration: 0.45s;
}

.light-blue {
  background-color: rgb(0, 85, 255);
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

.light-green {
  background-color: rgb(17, 255, 0);
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="christmas-tree">
  <div class="tree-top">
    <div class="lights-top">
      <div class="light light-red"></div>
      <div class="light light-yellow"></div>
      <div class="light light-blue"></div>
      <div class="light light-green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tree-middle">
    <div class="lights-middle">
      <div class="light light-blue"></div>
      <div class="light light-red"></div>
      <div class="light light-green"></div>
      <div class="light light-yellow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tree-bottom">
    <div class="lights-bottom">
      <div class="light light-green"></div>
      <div class="light light-yellow"></div>
      <div class="light light-red"></div>
      <div class="light light-blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="play-pause">
    <button onclick="pauseButton()">Pause / Resume</button>
  </div>
</div>
<audio id="christmasSong" controls>
  <source src="I Saw Mommy Kissing Santa Claus Jackson 5-GPNu0H6jNJc-192k-1702586134.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Please clarify what the issue is. Your title indicates you are having trouble pausing the animation, but your question body indicates that you can't add audio.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that when the javascript code is excuted to query the song it is not yet loaded and all the audioContext code cannot execute unless it is defined.

you can fix this in several ways, the second one being the one which allow you to have a better code organization but also the one that requieres more js understanding.

1. query within the pauseButton function

```
function pauseButton() {
  
const lights = document.querySelectorAll(".light");
const christmasSong = document.getElementById('christmasSong');
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(christmasSong);
audioSource.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  if (play === false) {
    lights.forEach((light) => {
    ...
```

dont forget to make an if statement so the audioContext is iniatilized only  only the first time you click that button

2. you can chek with window.addEventListener that the dom content has been loaded like this:

```
let play = false;
let christmasSong = null;
let audioContext = null;
let gainNode = null;
let lights = null;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  lights = document.querySelectorAll(".light");
  christmasSong = document.getElementById('christmasSong');
  audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
  const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(christmasSong);
  audioSource.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
 

});

function pauseButton() {
 
  audioContext.resume();
```

dont forget to resume the audioContext since chrome will not allow it to start unless you can check